# Whom or Which for the 100th time

Tags: grammar

I can't figure it out, minus 2 for me BUT for the 100th time, is it whom or which?

"...a group of people for whom I have the utmost respect for."

OR

"...a group of people for which I have the utmost respect for."

Comment: Answered at [What is the correct relative pronoun for 'government'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68790/what-is-the-correct-relative-pronoun-for-government); there is another duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative *who* can refer to people either as individuals or as a collective group.

> The directors of ABC, Ltd are people for whom I have the utmost respect.
>   The Board of ABC, Ltd is a group for whom I have the utmost respect.

Relative *which* can only refer to 'non-personal' or 'neuter' entities, so *a group of people for **which** I have the utmost respect can only mean that you have respect for the group, an entity which can be construed as non-personal:

> The Board of ABC, Ltd. is a group for which I have the utmost respect.

But as a practical matter you should avoid putting the interpretive burden on the relative. When you speak of *a **group** of **people** for who/which...*, you are pretty much setting your sentence up to sound awkward whichever relative you use. You can preclude that by unambiguously identifying the object of your respect as individuals with a plural noun or as a collective with a singular noun.